# Youtube Data API search.list malfunctioning for live streams

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are finding that the YouTube API is intermittently misreporting zero live streams within channel searches when specifically asking for `eventType=live`. It seems the timing for this issue is random but, for example, the following API call will either return everything or nothing, without changing any parameters. Our quota is fine. The channel (and many others we have tried) have multiple live webcam streams on 24/7 so they are not all going on and offline from one second to the next.

This is the API call (with API key removed):

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=live&type=video&channelId=UCY6XpD-K4mNk_C97pMiMJ8A&maxResults=50&key=(removed)`.

It’ll work sometimes, and not other times. At any attempt there are many live streams in that channel.

The “nothing” response is as follows:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "LgldeqxlASUfgtUiqLulF4E6Tcw",
  "regionCode": "GB",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 0,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  "items": []
}
```

Which is wrong at the time of the request.

If we remove `eventType=live` then when this issue is occurring we notice the live streams‘s `liveBroadcastContent` parameter are all marked with `none` instead of `live`.

This appears to be an API bug and it’s hindering development of our tool. Please help!

Pat

Comment: The YouTube API is not real-time.  Its got a delay sometimes its substantial sometimes its not.  Unless this stream you are expecting to see is a few days old i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: The channel has multiple live streams on 24/7. The API call can work in one second and not in the next. It is random and doesn‘t seem to be to do with caching.

Comment: You may want to post a bug report im not sure this is something that SO can help you with https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B

Comment: Ah thank you. I only found links to SO from the Google docs.

Comment: im not surprised one bit.  <shakes head>

Comment: Seems you are not the only one https://stackoverflow.com/q/68217741/1841839

Comment: @Pat reported: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192383337